# Binary reader for packet contents?

Tags: c#, vb.net, packet, packet-capture, binaryreader

I have created an app that retrieves network packets using this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4217/Packet-Sniffing-with-Winpcap-Functions-Ported-to-a

My intention is to use it in order to obtain the content of specific packets sent to a specific application from a server, I'm not interested in any other packets. The packet I'm interesting is 1 value which updates periodically.

I converted it to VB .Net as that is my preference so I'll be giving my code snippets in VB, though I can understand C# as well so feel free to give examples using C#.

It has an event with the parameter 's' which contains the content of the received packet in a byte array.

I'm converting that array to read with a binary reader like this:

```
Dim stream As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(s)
Dim reader As New System.IO.BinaryReader(stream)
Dim pos As Long = 0
Dim length As Long = reader.BaseStream.Length
```

I'll then go through a loop with the 'pos' variable as the current position, incremented by the data type of the current bytes. (Like: something = reader.ReadString() pos += something.Length)

My only problem is: I'm not sure what types I should be looking for? What is the 'structure' of a packet? Is it possible to retrieve the server that the packet was sent from, and the application it was sent to?

I've never tried using something like this for packets before, I've only had experience getting data from a custom format database file.

---

Edit: I've found something a bit more useful which has documentation explaining about source/destination IP and how to filter by them and it looks to be a lot more complete than the above example mentioned earlier.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12458/SharpPcap-A-Packet-Capture-Framework-for-NET

Though it still doesn't give an explanation of how to understand the packet contents itself, but being able to filter the packets is a big help.

Comment: Frankly, `BinaryReader`'s main usage is to read data that was written with `BinaryWriter`. Since that isn't the case here: *forget about `BinaryReader`* - it isn't going to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different types of possible network packets - most are well documented.

What you'll want to do is download Wireshark (Microsoft also has a similar tool whose name escapes me right now), run some captures with that, and look at the logs.

Wireshark recognizes virtually every existing network packet in existence, so you can use its logs to determine what type of packet you need to be able to recognize and then google for its specification.